# Sencha Touch 2 Beta 2 Store Sync Issues

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In ST1.x I had no problem syncing an onlinestore to an offlinestore with the below method, now it seems that sync doesn't work in STB2. I can see the records being output on the console. Anyone else having this issue? I believe it may be a bug...

```
var remoteStore = Ext.getStore('UpdateConfig');
var localStore = Ext.getStore('UpdateLocalConfig');

remoteStore.each(function (record) {
    localStore.add(record.data);
    console.log(record.data);
});
localStore.sync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered on the [Sencha Touch 2 Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179669-STB2-Store-Sync-Broken) by TommyMaintz, but I wanted to give the answer here as well.

"One thing I think I see which is wrong is that you are adding a record to the LocalStore using the record.data. In ST2 we now have a Model cache. This means that if you create two instances with the exact same model and id, the second time you create that instance it will just return the already existing instance. This means that if you sync your local store, it won't recognize that record as a 'phantom' record because it already has an id. What you would have to do in your case if you want to make a "copy" of your record by using all the data but removing the id. This will generate a new simple id for it and when you save it to your local storage it will generate a proper local id for it.

When I tried doing this I noticed the "copy" method on Model hasn't been updated to handle this. If you apply the following override you should be able to do localStore.add(record.copy()); localStore.sync()"

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.ModelCopyFix', {
    override: 'Ext.data.Model',

    /**
     * Creates a copy (clone) of this Model instance.
     *
     * @param {String} id A new id. If you don't specify this a new id will be generated for you.
     * To generate a phantom instance with a new id use:
     *
     *     var rec = record.copy(); // clone the record with a new id
     *
     * @return {Ext.data.Model}
     */
    copy: function(newId) {
        var me = this,
            idProperty = me.getIdProperty(),
            raw = Ext.apply({}, me.raw),
            data = Ext.apply({}, me.data);

        delete raw[idProperty];
        delete data[idProperty];

        return new me.self(null, newId, raw, data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this here. Solved the same issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

same question + answer @ [Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179669-STB2-Store-Sync-Broken)

...and same user??? XD